# Sum of square of terms in binomial expansion

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

We have the binomial expansion as this
$$(x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}x^{n-k}y^k = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}x^{k}y^{n-k}$$

Is there a formula for $\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}^2x^{2k}y^{2(n-k)}$, the sum when the terms are squared? If that's impossible, maybe one for when $y^2 = 1 - x^2$ if that makes thing easier? I've been thinking about it but couldn't figure anything out. I know it was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1375952/sum-of-squares-of-terms-of-a-binomial-expansion) in a somewhat similar fashion but there was not conclusive answer. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I know that there is a formula which says $$ {2n \choose n} = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}^2$$

Comment: The comment of @LuckyChouhan is **not coincidental**.  In your original expression, consider the coefficient of $~x^n~$ in the expansion of $~(x + y)^n \times (x+y)^n.~$  As $~k~$ traverses $~0~$ through $~n~$, you will have $~n+1~$ terms to add, each one of the form $$\left[\binom{n}{k} x^k y^{n-k}\right] \times \left[\binom{n}{k} x^{n-k} y^k\right].$$

Comment: Re my previous comment, typo: should be the coefficient of $~\color{red}{x^n y^n}.~$  Also, re my previous comment, this doesn't directly address your question, since you are interested in terms of the form $$\binom{n}{k}^2 x^{2k}y^{n-2k}.~$$ However, it *might* be a reasonable place to start.

Comment: Apparently there is an identity that would get rid of the squaring, but you'd still have a product of binomial coefficients, in case that ever helps: [Prove that $\sum_{l=0}^{n} \binom{n}{l}^2 (x+y)^{2l} (x-y)^{2(n-l)} = \sum_{l=0}^{n} \binom{2l}{l} \binom{2(n-l)}{n-l} x^{2l}y^{2(n-l)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2472978)

Comment: There also seems to be another identity, tis time in the form of an integral, in this answer: [An integral involving Bessel function of the first kind of the Sonine-Gegenbauer sort](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2828676), namely: $$2\pi \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2 a^{2k} b^{2n-2k} = \int_{0}^{2\pi}(a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\phi)^n\,d\phi$$ In case that becomes useful somehow?